# Looping through post data and updating corresponding database records

Tags: php

I am trying to loop through some data I post through jQuery.  Here is my PHP script:

```
<?php
include '../dbconnect.php';
$map = $_POST['map'];
$position = 0;
foreach ($map as $ID)
{
  if ($_POST['type'] == "sub") {
    $query = "UPDATE Subcategories SET `Position` = '$position' WHERE CategoryID = '$ID';";
  } else {
    $query = "UPDATE Categories SET `Position` = '$position' WHERE CategoryID = '$ID';";
  }

  $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
  $position ++;
}
?>
```

and the data it is recieving as $map is sent in this format:

> ID[]=27&ID[]=28&ID[]=33&ID[]=19

Obviously my `foreach` is wrong, but how would I go about getting it so that I retain `$map`s order and each numerical value becomes the variable `$ID`?

Comment: Do you mean that $_POST['map'] is coming through as a single element array ($_POST['map'][0] only is set) with the above string in it?  Where you actually want each individual ID to go through the foreach?

Comment: A sample output of what $_POST['map'] contains would help

Comment: It should be `$map = $_POST['ID'];` no?

Comment: Also you need to definitely sanitize every element $ID that you read before putting it even near a query.

Comment: @Gaurav output is up there already, @Darcara $_POST['map'] is correct because It is posted through this piece of jquery:    `$.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'updatecategoryposition.php',
     data: "map=" + map + "&type=sub" 
   });` @Pete I don't know how to get each individual which is the problem, I never actually land on this page so i can't echo out variable's etc as Jquery posts to this page in the background, the data is a function in a drag and drop plugin I use to serialize the output.

Comment: Is `ID[]=27&ID[]=28&ID[]=33&ID[]=19` a string, that $map holds?

Comment: Can you show us your form also? And how you are serializing the data?

Comment: @Starx yes indeed it is a string I post, I can't show you the form as the data is built by a drag and drop jquery plugin from the function:              `map = $(this).sortable("serialize");` and isn't produced from a form as such.

Comment: Ok, George, you can check my answer, should work, for your need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, Since your $map contains, `ID[]=27&ID[]=28&ID[]=33&ID[]=19` string value. Do something like this

```
$str = str_replace($map, "ID[]=","");
$mArr = explode("&", $str);
foreach($mArr as $key) {
   //now your $key will have 27, 28, 33, 19 as the loop progresses
}
```

<sub>P.S. Based on the OP's comment of $map having a string output of that</sub>

Comment: It should say `explode` instead of `expode`, and it's not what op has and should work.

Comment: @Darcora, Ok, explode is corrected. You know `typos` right :P

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure, but is this what you meant?  It works, if I understand your problem correctly.

```
<?php
include '../dbconnect.php';
$position = 0;

$pattern = '/ID\\[\\]=(\d+)&*/';
$subject = $_POST['map'];

 preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);

foreach ($matches as $k => $ID) {
  // etc
```

**Test Case**

Try this test, in a separate script.  The output from $matches[1] are what you would feed to the foreach loop if you used this script.  Does this retrieve what you want?

```
<?php
$pattern = '/ID\\[\\]=(\d+)&*/';
$subject = 'ID[]=27&ID[]=28&ID[]=33&ID[]=19';
preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);
echo '<pre>'.print_r($matches,1).'</pre>';
?>
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => ID[]=27&
        [1] => ID[]=28&
        [2] => ID[]=33&
        [3] => ID[]=19
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 27
        [1] => 28
        [2] => 33
        [3] => 19
    )

)
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not functioning for me :(

Comment: Hm, the regex itself works, since I tested it myself.  I'll update my post with just a test thing for you to try.  If that works, you could modify the example to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us what `print_r($map);` displays.

If it's just a string in the format you've described, I'd suggest changing the format of map to something easier to loop through like json. For example

```
{"map":[27,28,33,19]}
```

Then you can use

```
<?php
$mapObject = json_decode($_POST['map']);

$mapArray = $mapObject->map;
foreach($mapArray as $id)
{
    echo $id;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can POST it without the map, just

```
$.ajax({ type: 'POST', url: 'updatecategoryposition.php', data: map + "&type=sub" });
```

I'm assuming that map contains 'ID[]=27&ID[]=28&ID[]=33&ID[]=19'

As an alternative you can save the map in a different format so you end up with map being just a list of IDs ($map="27,28,33,19"), use the original jquery post and finally use

```
$map = explode(',' $_POST['map']);
```

Comment: I dont choose how map is formatted unfortunately that is a function in the plugin that produces the string as such.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for trying guys, but in the end I couldn't get any suggestions to work but I did find a solution:

Update category position:

```
<?php
include '../dbconnect.php';
foreach ($_POST['ID'] as $position => $ID){
$query = "UPDATE Subcategories SET `Position` = '$position' WHERE CategoryID = '$ID';";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
}
?>
```

and the new Jquery post request courtesy of Starx (telling me to remove variable name), as a result I can access the query string as above:

```
$.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: 'updatecategoryposition.php',
              data: map
            });
```